# Character matching before number regex

Tags: regex, tags, numbers, character

Ok, guys please help me with problem:

I have regexp which is matching numbers with different forms `([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)`, but i want to check for different characters before this number, for example `#` and it should work in strings with tags.

Example: I want to transform `<text>99.0</text>` to `<number>99.0</number>`
and if there is `#` character before then skip this part.
`<text>#99.0</text>` shouldn't transform.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use xml/html parsers. Manipulating xml/html data with regex is bad practice

Comment: add `(?<!#)` at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<text>([^#]*?[\d\.]+.*?)<\/text>` and `<number>$1</number>` for the substitution. [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/DH5QFs/1/)